# Error to get local fabric runtime to work

Tags: visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying out the IBM BLockchain Extension for VSCode and going through the tutorial. I am able to create a smart contract project, add a workplace, and create a smart contract package. At the local fabric ops part -  When I click start local fabric runtime I get an error:

> [5/19/2019 10:17:44 AM] [INFO] startFabricRuntime [5/19/2019 10:17:44
>   AM] [INFO] 'generate.cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, [5/19/2019 10:17:44 AM] [INFO] operable program or batch
>   file.

I am using:

- VSCode
- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Docker Desktop for Windows

Comment: Suggest you raise an issue as it could be a bug on windows. https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues make sure you fill in the details such as versions being used.

Comment: Thanks. I opened up an issue earlier today. Are you familiar with that error message?

Comment: I'm not, sorry. Have you tried tearing down the fabric and restarting ?

Comment: I have. The team is troubleshooting it in the github issue section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Uninstall ibm blockchain extension from extension
2. Delete runtime folder from vscode directory.

You can find vscode directory in home directory
path to runtime package
$ cd .fabric-vscode
$ ls
local_fabric_wallet  packages  runtime

$ rm packages

Reinstall the ibm blockchain extension in vscode